# Convert a string sheet to an object sheet VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to convert an array which contains the name of my sheets, but as Object and not as String

For example, I have this :

`arr=(Sheet01, Sheet02, Sheet03)`

When I add a Watches on my array, I get the type Variant/Object/Sheet01 and that's I need for.

But I would like to not hardcoding my namesheet and use a Range like :

`arr = Worksheets("Data").Range("NameSheet")`

But when I use this solution I get the type Variant/Variant but I need the object type for after use something like :

`Set SheCurrent = arr(i)`

Is there possible to do something like that ? Thanks for the help and sorry for the approximate english

Comment: What exactly is in the NameSheet range - the *tab* names or the *code* names of the worksheets?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to convert a array of strings into an array of worksheet objects:

```
Sub WhatsInAName()
    arr = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Dim oArr(1 To 3) As Worksheet
    i = 1
    For Each a In arr
        Set oArr(i) = Sheets(a)
        i = i + 1
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets are part of a Workbook. Every workbook has a `collection` of `worksheets` that you can access either by name of by number. If you write `Worksheets("Data")`, it accesses the worksheet *"Data"* of the current active workbook.

So the simple answer would be

```
Set SheCurrent = worksheets(arr(i))
```

But I would advice to read a little bit about how to deal with Workbooks and Worksheets in VBA, for example [10 ways to reference Excel workbooks and sheets using VBA](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/). As a general advice, you should (nearly) never assume a specific workbook to be active.